# SnapBack WaveGestureListener on Motorola Moto X

Tags: android, motorola, proximitysensor, snapback

I'm running the SnapBack sample [Snap4Magic](https://github.com/SnapbackLabs/android-sdk-samples/tree/master/Snap4Magic) on my testing device Motorola Moto X.
The app starts correctly on it but when i wave above the sensor SnapBack write to the logcat these messages and the right action is not launched.
What's the problem?

```
09-17 18:08:45.933  32197-32197/io.snapback.snap4magic D/SnapbackSdk﹕ FAR
09-17 18:08:45.934  32197-32211/io.snapback.snap4magic E/SnapbackSdk﹕ exception occurred: processSequenceStart discarded a non SEQUENCE_START_EVENT event
09-17 18:08:46.118  32197-32197/io.snapback.snap4magic D/SnapbackSdk﹕ FAR
09-17 18:08:46.119  32197-32211/io.snapback.snap4magic E/SnapbackSdk﹕ exception occurred: processSequenceStart discarded a non SEQUENCE_START_EVENT event
09-17 18:08:46.241  32197-32197/io.snapback.snap4magic D/SnapbackSdk﹕ FAR
09-17 18:08:46.242  32197-32211/io.snapback.snap4magic E/SnapbackSdk﹕ exception occurred: processSequenceStart discarded a non SEQUENCE_START_EVENT event
09-17 18:08:46.426  32197-32197/io.snapback.snap4magic D/SnapbackSdk﹕ FAR
09-17 18:08:46.427  32197-32211/io.snapback.snap4magic E/SnapbackSdk﹕ exception occurred: processSequenceStart discarded a non SEQUENCE_START_EVENT event
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue.

I tested [Snap4Magic](https://github.com/SnapbackLabs/android-sdk-samples/tree/master/Snap4Magic) on Motorola Moto X and I found a small bug which affects the normal behaviour of the adapter used by the example.

I just fixed the bug and the corrected version will be available in the next release.

Bye

Comment: Thanks, i'm waiting for the next release.